# Building react component library to CDN instead of NPM

Tags: reactjs, cdn, rollup, umd

I want to built a react library into a CDN instead of uploading to npm?

The library I wrote depends on some other libs (eg axios, react ...)
I'm using rollup to build umd, but then I try to install it in a project in the html script, when I import it, it says the axios library is not installed.

If anyone has ever built a library on CDN, please tell me, thank you very much.
Here is my config:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import pkg from './package.json';
import externalGlobals from 'rollup-plugin-external-globals';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
// import obfuscator from 'rollup-plugin-obfuscator';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: 'cjs',
            exports: 'named',
            name: 'lib',
        },
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'esm',
            exports: 'named',
            name: 'lib',
        },
        {
            file: pkg.iife,
            format: 'iife',
            exports: 'named',
            name: 'lib',
        },
        {
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: 'umd',
            exports: 'named',
            name: 'lib',
        },
    ],
    external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})],
    plugins: [
        terser(),
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript'),
        }),
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
        externalGlobals({
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        }),
        visualizer()
    ],
};
```

thank you!

Comment: A CDN is a service that sits as a proxy in front of your service and optimizes delivery of http resonses by serving it more local to the user. If you can host your code somewhere, you can pay for a CDN service. NPM seems unrelated to this.